# Google Cloud ML Engine: Create new model version with prediction logging enabled

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a model on ML engine and it doesn't have logging enabled.  I wanted to create a new version of the same pickled model with `onlinePredictionLogging=True`.

How can I do this through the ML Engine GUI?  All docs I've seen (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/models/create) are command-line based.

If I try to create a new version, I don't get to change the `ModelResource` that has the `onlinePredictionLogging` field...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible via Cloud Console (GUI). I will file a feature request.